# Encrypt using certificate

Tags: openssl, public-key

I have certificate in DER format that according to my understanding contains public key. I need to encrypt symmetric key with certificates public key according to standard at least RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5.

What command I should use in order to encrypt symmetric key? Should I somehow extract public key from certificate at first?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to do this manually? As PCKS is about RSA in general most implementation that already hadnle RSA encryption should be able to do this OOB? In addition why v 1.5 and not 2.2? It really depends on what your actual need is what the best course of action is.

Comment: This is project prototype and later encryption will be done by software. According requirements I need to use at least ver 1.5. What does OOB means?

Comment: Out of the box. It should be done in sofware right now. See [this Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271197/how-to-extract-public-key-using-openssl) question on how to extract the public key manually using openssl. If this is a web application or similar there are standard tools that will abstract the whole thing from you as it is kind of standard see e.g. [this question on HTTP/HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791013/https-uses-asymmetric-or-symmetric-encryption).